# Draw a curve between two random points and randomly place a point on this curve

Tags: geometry-nodes

I'm trying to create a curve between two points in a simple geometry.

I capture the position of vertex index 0 and 3, and I would like to create a curve between these two points. I tried with a [Bézier curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve) node and capturing the position of the selected vertices, but I can't get it to work.

The next steps will be to randomly sample the two initial vertices of the geometry and randomly place a point along the curve between those two vertices.

[image: Geometry]

[image: Node setup]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To do this, you would only have to capture the positions of your selected points with the node `Transfer Attributes` and use them as start/end points for your curve.

If you then capture a random position with the node `Sample Curve`, you can use this directly as the position for your sphere.

[image]

Comment: That's exactly what I needed and it works perfectly. I cannot upvote your answer because of low reputation but that's it.